# How to generate a pdf invoice from mySQL table using FPDF for a specfic id

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, invoice

I am facing a problem of getting the the data for a specific id. I want the user to get the link to download the data from a button. This is mysqldatatable name (add_courier):

id | order_inv | name | date | quantity of the items | price | payment mode.

Now, I am able to get the list of all the ids but I am not able to get the invoice for a specific id. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'lexipressdb');


class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header(){
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);

        //dummy cell to put logo
        //$this->Cell(12,0,'',0,0);
        //is equivalent to:
        $this->Cell(12);

        //put logo
        $this->Image('gift.jpg',10,10,10);

        $this->Cell(100,10,'Invoice',0,1);

        //dummy cell to give line spacing
        //$this->Cell(0,5,'',0,1);
        //is equivalent to:
        $this->Ln(5);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);

        $this->SetFillColor(180,180,255);
        $this->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);
        $this->Cell(40,5,'Order Invoice',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(25,5,'Quantity',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(65,5,'Weight',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(60,5,'Cost',1,1,'',true);

    }
    function Footer(){
        //add table's bottom line
        $this->Cell(190,0,'','T',1,'',true);

        //Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);

        //width = 0 means the cell is extended up to the right margin
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo()." / {pages}",0,0,'C');
    }
}


//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4'); //use new class

//define new alias for total page numbers
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from add_courier");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['order_inv'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['r_qnty'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['r_weight'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['r_costtotal'],'LR',1);

}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I want to have my format to be like this for each id so that the user can download it from the link:'

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');

$pdf->AddPage();

//set font to arial, bold, 14pt
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);

//Cell(width , height , text , border , end line , [align] )

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'Lexipress.CO',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59   ,5,'INVOICE',0,1);//end of line

//set font to arial, regular, 12pt
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'[Street Address]',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(59   ,5,'',0,1);//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'[City, Country, ZIP]',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Date',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,'[dd/mm/yyyy]',0,1);//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'Phone [+12345678]',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Invoice #',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,'[1234567]',0,1);//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'Fax [+12345678]',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Customer ID',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,'[1234567]',0,1);//end of line

//make a dummy empty cell as a vertical spacer
$pdf->Cell(189  ,10,'',0,1);//end of line

//billing address
$pdf->Cell(100  ,5,'Bill to',0,1);//end of line

//add dummy cell at beginning of each line for indentation
$pdf->Cell(10   ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(90   ,5,'[Name]',0,1);

$pdf->Cell(10   ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(90   ,5,'[Company Name]',0,1);

$pdf->Cell(10   ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(90   ,5,'[Address]',0,1);

$pdf->Cell(10   ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(90   ,5,'[Phone]',0,1);

//make a dummy empty cell as a vertical spacer
$pdf->Cell(189  ,10,'',0,1);//end of line

//invoice contents
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'Description',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Taxable',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,'Amount',1,1);//end of line

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

//Numbers are right-aligned so we give 'R' after new line parameter

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'UltraCool Fridge',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'-',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,'3,250',1,1,'R');//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'Supaclean Diswasher',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'-',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,'1,200',1,1,'R');//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'Something Else',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'-',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,'1,000',1,1,'R');//end of line

//summary
$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Subtotal',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(4    ,5,'$',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(30   ,5,'4,450',1,1,'R');//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Taxable',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(4    ,5,'$',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(30   ,5,'0',1,1,'R');//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Tax Rate',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(4    ,5,'$',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(30   ,5,'10%',1,1,'R');//end of line

$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,'',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,'Total Due',0,0);
$pdf->Cell(4    ,5,'$',1,0);
$pdf->Cell(30   ,5,'4,450',1,1,'R');//end of line

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I don't know how to go about it. Can someone please help? I've also checked the other questions for the same issues but i'm not getting the resloution.'

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from add_courier");
foreach loop starts here 
<button > <a href="printme.php&id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">Print</a>
</button>
```

for each loop ends here

in your FPDF page get the ID variable

//example//

```
require('fpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'lexipressdb');
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

alter your query with this on FPDF page

```
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from add_courier where id='$id'");
```

Comment: Hi Fahad, i tried this but i am getting an error of undefined variable.                   Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lexipress Pro\invoice\generate_pdf.php on line 5

Comment: can you please share your Invoice listing page code?

Comment: <?php
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select *from add_courier");
$cnt=1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

?>                                        
   <th>Tracking Id</th>  <td><?php echo $row['trackingid'];?></td>                                                                    
   <th>Print</th>                                                                                                                                      <a href="invoice/generate_pdf.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"Click</a>                    }

Comment: Here is the link to get the better clarity on the code part.                                               https://github.com/sachindahiya07/lol/blob/master/Invoice%20PDF

Comment: @sachindahiya please check your git link I've made some changes in your code

Comment: can't see any changes there. Can you please post it in the answer box.

Comment: https://github.com/fahadpatel/lol/commit/fa434db3391ed332115f1d6fb91a1923cc30c152?diff=unified

Comment: Thank you Fahad for the help. I tried as you've mentioned and i get the tracking id in the url but i want to fetch data of mysql  query on pdf.php page where instead of the getting the full report the user should be see his data only. There is issue with my pdf.php page

Comment: Again the same error of undefined variable in line 5 in this code on generate_pdf.php page:                                                                                                    <?php
require('fpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'lexipressdb');
$id=$_GET['id'];

Comment: Undefined which variable $id?

Comment: First initialize $id =""; the store the value In $id

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
                                  <thead>
                              <th style="font-weight:bold;">Tracking</th>
                              <th style="font-weight:bold;">Print Invoice</th>               

                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>

                 <?php
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select *from add_courier");
$cnt=1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

?>                                        
            <tr>

             <td style="font-weight:bold;"><?php  echo $row['trackingid'];?>
             </td>
             <td>
              <a href="invoice/generate_pdf.php?id=<?php  echo $row['trackingid'];
              //this is your tracking primary key column name
              ?>">Generate</a>
             </td>
             </tr>

<?php
}
?>           
</tbody>     
 </table>

          --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

generate_pdf.php code

```
 <?php
require('fpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con,'lexipressdb');
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

// please first echo and check the id value

```
echo $id; exit;
```

// if you get the id on clicking generate link then comment the above line and enjoy

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header(){
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);

        //dummy cell to put logo
        //$this->Cell(12,0,'',0,0);
        //is equivalent to:
        $this->Cell(12);

        //put logo
        $this->Image('gift.jpg',10,10,10);

        $this->Cell(100,10,'Invoice',0,1);

        //dummy cell to give line spacing
        //$this->Cell(0,5,'',0,1);
        //is equivalent to:
        $this->Ln(5);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);

        $this->SetFillColor(180,180,255);
        $this->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);
        $this->Cell(40,5,'Order Invoice',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(25,5,'Quantity',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(65,5,'Weight',1,0,'',true);
        $this->Cell(60,5,'Cost',1,1,'',true);

    }
    function Footer(){
        //add table's bottom line
        $this->Cell(190,0,'','T',1,'',true);

        //Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);

        //width = 0 means the cell is extended up to the right margin
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo()." / {pages}",0,0,'C');
    }
}


//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4'); //use new class

//define new alias for total page numbers
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from add_courier where id='$id'");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['order_inv'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['r_qnty'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['r_weight'],'LR',0);
    $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['r_costtotal'],'LR',1);

}



$pdf->Output();
?>
```